# Deep link crashes when app is not in background

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking

for some reason my deep link keeps crashing every time I click it. and this only happens when my application is not running in the background. it impossible for me to get the error message because it only happens when the app is not running. I really need you guys to help, please. is there a way to solve this issue? keep in mind that I pass some parameters too but I don't think that's an issue because like I said it works fine when the app is running.

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"www.tes.post/vp/"+strArray+"/"+userid);
                                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "tes");
                                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

Below is the code of how I get this parameters¨.

```
   Uri cheint = getIntent().getData();
    if (cheint!=null)
    {
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        List<String> p = data.getPathSegments();

        userid = p.get(2);
        postkey = p.get(1).replaceAll("_", " ");
        type = p.get(0);
    }
```